# How to do a screenshot when my iPhone receive a call

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode10, callkit

I want to manage incoming calls action to take a screenshot. Screenshot is made but there isn't my incoming call screen. How can I achieve this?

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
var callObserver: CXCallObserver!
var photoDelegate: UIImageView!
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    callObserver = CXCallObserver()
    callObserver.setDelegate(self, queue: nil) // nil queue means main thread
    return true
}
}
```

And the CXCallObserverDelegate

```
extension AppDelegate: CXCallObserverDelegate {
func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {
    if call.hasEnded == true {

    }
    if call.isOutgoing == true && call.hasConnected == false {      
    }
    if call.isOutgoing == false && call.hasConnected == false && call.hasEnded == false {
        print("Incoming \(call.uuid.description)")
 imagine = UIImageView(image: UIApplication.shared.screenShot!)
    }

    if call.hasConnected == true && call.hasEnded == false {

  }
}
}
```

The Screenshot of the screen

```
extension UIApplication {

var screenShot: UIImage?  {

    if let rootViewController = keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        let bounds = rootViewController.view.bounds
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, scale);
        if let _ = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            rootViewController.view.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return screenshot
        }
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CallKit UI that is displayed when the user receives a call is part of iOS and not your app, upon answering the call the app takes the focus and you can take screenshots.

[Replaykit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit) can be an alternative solution.